# How to seperate logs into separate files daily in Node.js using Winston library

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, winston

I have a node.js app. I need to log each event in this program and I use winston library for this. I am trying to create a log file for each day. All logs should be separated day by day. I want to save the daily files on my desktop. For example the requests (actions in my program) that I have done today will be saved as 18/10/2019.log on my desktop. And tomorrow when I do some requests again (e.g: get, post) should be logged as 19/10/2019.log on desktop again. I can't do this. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** SOLVED!!

With winston-daily-rotate-file, it is resolved. To use that module:

```
npm install winston-daily-rotate-file
```

THE CODE:

```
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const logDir= 'C://Users/Desktop/LogFiles';

var options = {
     file: {
       level:'info',
       filename: path.resolve(`${logDir}/${new 
  Date().getFullYear().toString()} - ${new Date().getMonth()+1}/%DATE%.log`),
       datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
       timestamp: new Date()
      };


 let logger = winston.createLogger({
  level:'info', 
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.printf(info => { return `${info.timestamp} || 
  ${info.level} || Message: ${info.message}`; })
  ),

    transports: [
     new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile(options.file)
      ],  
       exitOnError: false,
});
```

Comment: Try daily appender for log file with setting

Comment: I don't understand how

Comment: The solution for this in the bolow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45479473/log4js-javascript-create-daily-log-file

Comment: There is package for this, https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-daily-rotate-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install winston daily rotate

`npm install winston-daily-rotate-file`

**Note:** Check for compatibility [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file#compatibility) first

```
 var winston = require('winston');
  require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

  var fileRotateTransport = new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
    filename: '%DATE%.log',
    datePattern: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    maxSize: '20m'
  });

  var logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
      fileRotateTransport 
    ]
  });
```

Check for the winston daily [rotate options](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file#options) to configure as per your requirements.

Comment: Error: No such file or directory, mkdir '21/10\'

Comment: @MinelAydın Do you need date format as DD/MM/YYYY? Can it be DD-MM-YYYY, because if I do this then it works fine. I think / is considered as directory by winston-daily-rotate-file library.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Change errorLogFileName to date format which is comfortable to you. Logs will be appended to same file on same day.
New file is created if date will changes.

```
**let errorLogFileName =  new Date().toLocaleDateString()+'error.log';**
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: errorLogFileName, level: 'error' }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried this, but where this code saved my log files?

Comment: let errorLogFileName =  'logs/ '+new Date().toLocaleDateString()+'error.log'; It will create files under "logs" folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
var winston = require('winston');

function getLogger(module) {
    var path = module.filename.split('/').slice(-2).join('/');

    return winston.createLogger({
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.Console({
                colorize: true,
                level: 'debug',
                label: path
            })
        ]
    });
}

module.exports = getLogger;
```

put this seperate file in project file

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create each folder with Date()

Example : 3052021 (For 30-MAY-2021)

[image]

```
let errorLogFolderName =  new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/\D/g, ''); //creating folders each day

function logger() {
  return createLogger({
    //level: 'info',
    format: combine(
      timestamp(),
      errors({ stack: true }),
      printf(info => {
        return `${info.timestamp} [${info.level}] : ${(info.stack || info.message)}`;
      })
    ),
    transports: [
        new transports.File({ filename: `./logs/${errorLogFolderName}/dailylog.log` })
    ]
  });
}
```